# How to make a Bot listen to a conversation in the background, but respond only if his name is quoted in a sentence

Tags: response, python-3.7, chatbot, chatterbot

I am developing a ChatBot for Telegram named "Joker". It works perfectly in a private conversation. Has a whole training set up to answer several questions. But when placed in a group, it responds to all messages sent to the group, creating a chat disorder. It would be nice if my Bot could hear the group talk in the background and intervene only if his name "Joker" is quoted in one sentence. He would normally answer the questions as long as the word "Joker" was contained in the sentence. For this reason, I am trying to implement this feature, but it does not work as it should.

**Current Reaction**

> - **Gillan:** Good morning guys!
> - **Mitzi Dupree:** Good morning, Gillan!

... Joker is typing

> - **Gillan:** Good morning, Joker!

... Joker is typing

> - **Gillan:** Joker?

... Joker is typing

Communication.py

```
def respond(self, message):
    """
    Receive message from user and returns corresponding answer.
    """
    if re.search("joker", message, re.IGNORECASE):
        joker_in_message = True
    else:
        joker_in_message = False

    message_without_joker = re.sub(r'\bjoker\b', '', message, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    #remove duplicate spaces
    message_without_joker = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', message_without_joker)

    if joker_in_message and len(message) > 50 and self.watson_usage:
        top_answer = get_analysis(message_without_joker)
        return f"Hmm, you're talking about {top_answer}"
    if joker_in_message and len(message.strip()) == len("joker"):
        return "Something wrong is not right, text me what "\
               "you told my creators!" \
               "Type /info to learn more."
    elif joker_in_message:
        return self.comm.get_response(self.clean(message_without_joker))
```

Application.py

```
def text_message(self, bot, update):
    self.send_type_action(bot, update)  
    if not self.check_for_emotion(update):
        message = update.effective_message.text
        answer = self.comm.respond(message)
        if answer:
            update.effective_message.reply_text(answer)
    return 0
```